# round each row in a file bash

Tags: bash, list, rounding, bc

I'm processing some data using `bash`.  I'm checking whether the data is complete by summing up the first column.  It should consist of 0 - 500 with 0.1 increment.  Unfortunately, the actual numbers are slightly off so that the sum can equal  1250653.9 instead of 1250250.0 .   This could be avoided if I rounded each number before summing.  Currently, I use the following:

```
cat L_z_expectation.dat | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Is there a way of pasting "+0.0001" to each row, then individually piping each row to bc in a single line?

Comment: A minor aside: You dont need the `cat` command. You could just pass the filename as the second paramter to `awk`. See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just appending it awk would be fine I think.

```
cat L_z_expectation.dat | awk '{ print $1 "+0.0001"}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Or do you need to omit paste instead?

```
cat L_z_expectation.dat | awk '{ print $1 "+0.0001"}' | bc
```

Comment: Ahh of course. Thats a great idea.  It works well, but when I try to set the scale it doesnt work. the first bc still returns the numbers to their full precision
   .

`cat L_z_expectation.dat | awk '{print "scale=1;"$1"+0.0000000001"'} | bc | paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: Forgot that bc wont set a scale with addition.  I fixed it by dividing by 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Most implementations of awk seem to use double-precision floating numbers, so it can be enough for what you want.

So you can use only `awk` for what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=0;} {s+=$1} END {print s}' L_z_expectation.dat
```

You may need to use `printf` instead `print` to display numbers with enough precision.

If you still want to round the first column, you can then do the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=0;} {s+=int($1+0.5)} END {print s}' L_z_expectation.dat
```